# C# read values from json sequentially

Tags: c#, json, vector

I'm trying to get the values sequentially from the following json:

```
    {
        "FacePreset1" : {
           "Overall_Face_Breadth": {"x":0.35, "y":0.45},
           "Upper_face_depth": {"x":0.3, "y":0.45"},
           "Face_height": {"x":0.4, "y":0.52},
           "Lower_face_depth": {"x":0.45, "y":0.6},
           "Lower_face_width": {"x":0.1, "y":0.4}
        }
    }
```

And here's some C# code:

```
    [System.Serializeable]
    public class Token
    {
        public FacePreset FacePreset1;
    }
     
    [System.Serializeable]
    public class FacePreset1
    {
        public Vector2 Overall_Face_Breadth;
        public Vector2 Upper_face_depth;
        public Vector2 Face_height;
        public Vector2 Lower_face_depth;
        public Vector2 Lower_face_width;
    }   
    
    public Vector2 currentkey;
    
    void RandomiseCharBody()
    {
      var token = JsonUtility.FromJson<Token>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(json1.json));
    
      int slider = 0;
      while (slider <= 4) 
      { 
        Vector2 currentkey = token.FacePreset1.Overall_Face_Breadth;
        female.customInfo.shapeValueBody[slider] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(currentkey.x, currentkey.y);
        slider++;
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to get the values from Overall_Face_Breadth, then proceed to the next key (Upper_face_depth) inside the while loop without needing to do each key individually?

I think it can be done with foreach instead of a while loop but i don't know how.

Comment: What do you mean sequentially? When you read json, you read the entire thing

Comment: Use the JTokens directly, also this seems like an xy problem, people who wrote the json shouldn't have made order matter, nor should your code

Comment: Having your {x, y} objects as a Json array would make it easy for you to iterate on it after parsing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every property of your class is a Vector2 you could do it using reflection.

```
using System.Reflection;
foreach (FieldInfo field in token.FacePreset1.GetType().GetFields()){
                 Vector2 currentkey=(Vector2)field.GetValue(token.FacePreset1);
}
```